# Number theory sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

consider the sequence $\left\{ { 2 }^{ n }-3:n\ge 2 \right\} =\left\{ 1,5,13,29.61,125,... \right\}  $ .

Shows that it contains an infinity of numbers divisible by 5 and an infinity of numbers divisible by 13, but does not contain a number divisible by $5\cdot 13$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you just listed some terms?  $2^n-3 \pmod 5$ repeats, as does $2^n-3 \pmod {13}$

Comment: The sequence $$2^n-3\mod 65$$ is periodic with length $12$. SInce no zero appears, but $5$ and $13$ appear, the claim easily follows.